# Css for gridview

Tags: html, asp.net, css, gridview

I developed a gridview by following this tutorial but i want to change it's css, can someone point me to right direction please,

Here's a little bit of markup

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1"
runat="server"
DataKeyNames="CustomerID" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
OnRowDataBound="gv_RowDataBound" Width="80%"
AllowPaging="True" PageSize="20" cssClass="myclass" />
```

I added a css class but not sure what will go in class so that I make my gridview attractive,

Comment: Your gridview will be rendered like a table (just check HTML source of rendered apx page), so you'll need to style a table with class myclass in CSS. Eventually you can give other classes to rows or even cell, but still you'll need to define it in a css file...

Comment: @Bartdude thanks that is helpful, do you know any post which is doing it, so that I can follow it please

Comment: Do you know about CSS at all actually ? I would consider learning about it as a start... Then if you got specific problem, SO can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check below codeproject link. This may help you.

[Add some style to your datagrids](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7645/Add-some-Style-to-your-DataGrids)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the this : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx . Skin is easy to maintain and change

Comment: On the other hand I'm quite sure it will generate inline-style, which is not to be recommended...